# angular upload a file - formdata.get is empty

Tags: angular, file-upload

i am trying to upload a file

this, is my swagger api i am trying to call [image]

my service
[image]

my function that is calling http request [image]

this is a console log of a const file
[image]

and this is a payload of my http request
[image]
and error from response
[image]

Comment: Have you tried just sending the `formData` in the post request? Instead of `{file..`

Comment: this is the payload of sending only `formData` https://prnt.sc/1qm2on7 error is the same as displayed above; file is required, sending `{file: formData}` is empty object as well

Comment: how about just `{file: file}`?

Comment: @eko object file is empty as in screenshot

Comment: object `file` is not empty in the logs, you show the request payload is empty which is `formData.get('file')`

Comment: @eko and why is request payload empty but not the file object empty ?

Comment: Right now I don't know but then your questions turns into why does `formData.get` returns an empty object, right? So did my previous suggestion work?

Comment: it returns empty payload, nothing worked yet

Comment: ok just to double check: even if you pass `{file:file}` in the post request you see an empty object in the request payload, is that right?

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - remove images of your code and add properly formatted code and error responses.

Comment: after removing content type from service and pasting only clear formData upload works like a charm