# While submitting after uploading file, form data seems to be blank

Tags: angular

I am trying to upload multiple files in angular-11, so on submitting the form, `FormData` object is showing blank on console, however, I already appended the files.

**add-product.component.html**

```
<div class="display-flex flex-direction-column width-33">
   <label class="form-label control-label" for="file">Attachment</label>
   <input type="file" id="file" (change)="upload($event)" class="form-control" formControlName="attachment">
</div>
```

**add-product.component.ts**

```
upload(event: any) {
    let files = event.target.files;
    let fData: FormData = new FormData();
    let file :Array<any> = [];
    console.log("files",files)
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        fData.append("file", files);
        console.log("fData inside loop",fData)
    }
    //fData.append("data", JSON.stringify(_data));
    console.log("fData",fData)
    console.log("files[i]",files[0])
}
```

I am not able to figure out what went wrong with `FormData` object, I have gone through a lot of posts but didn't get much help. The conclusion is I am not able to upload files or more precisely not able to send binary data to the server. Please suggest to me the best solution for the same.

The snapshot for reference has been attached below -

[image]

**Edits**

I am getting this on network tab, how I can see my uploaded files?

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to do `fData.append("file", files[i]);` instead of `fData.append("file", files);`?

Comment: I already tried `fData.append("file", files[i]);` but this is also not working.

Comment: The data is actually there. But because of the nature of formData, you can’t simply inspect it. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031766/angular-form-data-wont-append

Comment: @MikeOne Okay got it, Please see my edits and let me know if you are talking about this, how can I view my uploaded files?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with ‘view my files’? Most files are binary and formData converts your file to an encoded text format. Not really much to see there besides a huge long string of characters..

Comment: This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68953625/angular-upload-a-file-formdata-get-is-empty#comment121863012_68953625